# Find <a> with only one img tag in it

Tags: php, regex

How would a regex look to find all `a` tags with only one `img` tag in it.

this shows an example:
`<a href="somelink"><img src="somelink" border="0"/></a>`

It should also match if a linebreak occurs between the `img` tag and the `a` tag.

thanks for your help

Comment: I tried this: `/<a[^>]+>[ |\r]?<img[^>]+>[ |\r]?</a>/` because there should only occur an `img` tag in the `a` tag. But no php complains about `Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'a' in`

Comment: That error results from the fact that you're using `/` both as a regex delimiter and as a literal character within the regex.

Comment: Do you mean that there may be nothing but a single `img` tag within the `a` tag (besides whitespace)? Or that anything is allowed within the `a` tag as long as there is at most one `img` tag there?

Comment: I ment there should only be a `<img>` tag in the `a` tag.

Comment: It's a pretty good bet that this would be easier and more reliable using `DOMDocument` than regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual disclaimer about how it's not 100 % reliable to parse HTML with regex applies. But if you are stuck with a regex, you could do this:

```
preg_match_all(
    '%<a\b[^<>]*>      # Match an opening <a> tag
    (?:(?!<img\b).)*   # Match any characters except <img> tags
    <img\b[^<>]*>      # Match one <img> tag
    (?:(?!<img\b).)*   # Match any characters except <img> tags
    </a>               # Match a closing <a> tag%sx', 
    $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = $result[0];
```

If you meant to allow nothing but a single `img` tag (plus optional whitespace), then it's a little easier:

```
preg_match_all(
    '%<a\b[^<>]*>  # Match an opening <a> tag
    \s*            # Match optional whitespace
    <img\b[^<>]*>  # Match one <img> tag
    \s*            # Match optional whitespace
    </a>           # Match a closing <a> tag%sx', 
    $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```